# I want to send the information from an form to an array en JavaScript and then display it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, database

Im trying this for so long and i dont know how to fix it. The idea is simple, The user insert the requiered data in the HTML forms, then the inserted data is stored in an array and display all the data with a text. I think the problem is when i try to store the data from the form into the array.

This is what ive done so far

```
<html>
    <header>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Second Homework</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>Please insert the data in the following form: </p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
            <input type="text" id="age"><br>
            <input type="text" id="city"><br>
            <input type="text" id="pet"><br>
            <input type="text" id="pet_name"><br>
            <button type="button" id="" onclick="data()">Enviar</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function data(){
            var info=[getElementById("name").innerHTML.value,getElementById("lname").innerHTML.value,
            getElementById("age").innerHTML.value,getElementById("city").innerHTML.value,getElementById("pet").innerHTML.value,getElementById("pet_name").innerHTML.value]
            document.write("Your name is: "+info[0])
            document.write("Your lastname is: "+info[1])
            document.write("You are "+info[2]+"  years old")
            document.write("You live in: "+info[3])
            document.write("Do you have pets? "+info[4])
            document.write("Your pets name is: "+info[5])
        }
    

        </script>
    </body>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: try document.getElementById("name")...

Comment: You need `document.getElementById("name").value`, same for the others.

Comment: Yes, you should use  .value instead of .innerHTML.value, like this: var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

Answer (score 0):

**in HTML, form inputs elements must use a `name` attribute**

do this way:

```js
 
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit
  
  let info = Array.from(new FormData(myForm).entries()).map(([k,v])=>v)
  
  document.write("<br>Your name is: "+info[0])
  document.write("<br>Your lastname is: "+info[1])
  document.write("<br>You are "+info[2]+"  years old")
  document.write("<br>You live in: "+info[3])
  document.write("<br>Do you have pets? "+info[4])
  document.write("<br>Your pets name is: "+info[5])

  /* ------------------------------- or
  let msg = `
    Your name is: ${myForm.name.value}
    Your lastname is: ${myForm.lname.value}
    You are ${myForm.age.value}  years old
    You live in ${myForm.city.value}
    Do you have pets? ${myForm.pet.value}
    Your pets name is: ${myForm.pet_name.value}`

    console.log( msg ) 
  ------------------------------------- */
  }
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>Please insert the data in the following form: </p>
<form name="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="name"     placeholder="name"     ><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname"    placeholder="last name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="age"      placeholder="age"      ><br>
  <input type="text" name="city"     placeholder="city"     ><br>
  <input type="text" name="pet"      placeholder="pet"      ><br>
  <input type="text" name="pet_name" placeholder="pet name" ><br>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```